# Retrieve all existing Id's of oView

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am kinda curious to know if there is a way to retrieve all existing id's of an oView.
Since I am running here and there into "undefined" errors and usually its a typo etc. That could be avoided by finding out which Id's were registered.

this.oView will get me a lot of functions and aggregations, but I couldn't find any list of id's

Comment: How does "finding out which IDs were registered" help to avoid typos? Can you elaborate on this a bit?

Comment: the same way as using ctrl+space in eclipse and other tools help you avoiding typos, because you just select from what is possible

Comment: So this question is about retrieving IDs during the development and not during the runtime. What tools / IDE are you currently using then?

Comment: ofc the Web IDE and of course the console of chrome, but I couldn't find any way of how to retrive all id's